# Error: Cannot find module 'rd'

Tags: node.js

rd module has been installed.

```
sudo npm install  rd  -g  
+ rd@1.0.0
added 1 package in 2.097s
```

To require it in node console.

```
node
> var rd = require('rd');
Error: Cannot find module 'rd'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
```

Why can't require it after installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it as locally, Remove `-g`

do

`npm install rd`

OR

`npm install rd --save` to save in `package.json` file

OR If your npm version is greater than 5

`npm install rd` will save by default in `package.json`